# Installing Ubuntu Desktop environment onto ubuntu gnome

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, 15.10

I have searched for an answer, but

```
sudo apt-get install unity-desktop
```

does not work for me.

I would like to install the Unity desktop on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10, so that I can switch between them from the login screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - I just entered:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

And it worked

Comment: What is the purpose of "\"?

Comment: that maybe by accident, I will remove.